# updating excel 2007 macro to excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have a reset button that resets and "temp" range to the "start" range.  It works in excel 2007,  but does not work in excel 2013.  the two statements are:

```
Range("start").Select

ActiveCell.Name = "Temp"
```

What needs to be changed to make this work in excel 2013?

Comment: **How** doesn't it work?

Comment: All I can say based on that is to declare the sheet names, maybe you have an active sheet thing going on..  It could be coincidence...

Comment: In 213, the "Temp" range is not reset to the "Start" range.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Sub dural()
    Range("Start").Parent.Activate
    Range("Start").Select
    ActiveCell.Name = "temp"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It did not work.  I have also tried the following:

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Names("Temp") = ActiveWorkbook.Names("Start")
 ActiveWorkbook.Names("Temp") = Range("start")